# Random gibberish lines in project

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened Eclipse as usual like every morning and suddenly I see random lines in some of my project's classes.

I tried to google it but without success.
I don't know from where eclipse implements those lines.
For example `=======`,`<<<<<<< HEAD`...

Is someone maybe know how can I delete those lines? Because it mess up the project code as well and deleting them by hand isn't working.
And is anyone knows why this happene?

```java
package com.saywut.tictactoe;

<<<<<<< HEAD
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
=======
import javax.swing.JFrame;
>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

<<<<<<< HEAD
public class TicTacToe
=======
public class TicTacToe 
>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
{
    public TicTacToe()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
<<<<<<< HEAD
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        GameGrid grid = new GameGrid(panel);
        GlassPane glassPane = new GlassPane();

        grid.addObserver(glassPane);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

=======
        FramePanel panel = new FramePanel();
        GlassPane glassPane = new GlassPane(panel.getGrid());

>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);
        glassPane.setVisible(true);
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======

>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
<<<<<<< HEAD

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
=======

    public static void main(String[] args)
>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
<<<<<<< HEAD
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
=======
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======

>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TicTacToe());
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you've done a merge and there were some conflicts

Comment: Those are merge conflicts. The lines between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` is the old version and the lines `=======` and `>>>>>>> 44d9a54bad5133d5125bc8013e9912fba15c0ef5` are the new version of it.

Comment: What kind of VCS are you using?

Comment: Ok now I know why, it because git. Thx